# Java - convert character to byte

Tags: java

All I want to do is read characters from a notepad and convert it to bytes and save it another file.

"a.txt" has the simple text in notepad "Hello World!"

However, in "b.txt", I still see the human readable characters instead of the byte values. I also noticed that when I do a `System.out.print(ba)`, it prints the bytes.

Can anyone tell me why Java does not write the byte values to "b.txt"?

```
import java.io.*;

class a {
    static int f;
    static String s;

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws IOException {
        BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("a.txt"));
        BufferedOutputStream w = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("b.txt"));

        byte ba[] = new byte[1024];

        while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
            ba = s.getBytes();
            System.out.print(ba);
            w.write(ba);
        }
    w.flush();
    w.close();
    br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does. You told it to write the exact same bytes it reads from "a.txt" to "b.txt" and it does. If you look at b.txt in a Hex-editor, you'll see the byte values.

Comment: Thanks Daniel ! Why do I need a hex editor? I thought saving as bytes would mean they are saved as the characters' integer value?

Comment: Basically, if you have a text file containing the text:

`Hello world`

That file is stored with an encoding. This means that the file will really contain the bytes:

`48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64`

Notepad "translates" these bytes into characters. If you read these bytes, and the write the bytes back to a new file, the file will be identical to the original file, and notepad will still "translate" the bytes to characters.

Comment: _Everything_ is stored as bytes on the disk. Each application interprets these bytes in some way. A text editor interprets them as a character encoding, a hex editor as numbers to display. So if you want to see the numbers, use a hex editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing raw byte values to the file.
Notepad reads them as ASCII text.

If you open either file in a hex editor, you will see the actual byte values.

If you want to see byte values in Notepad, you'll need to print each byte to the file as a string, typically separated by spaces so that you can see each one.

Answer (score 1):

You're copying a.txt byte-for-byte into b.txt. Of course it's going to appear as text, why wouldn't it? If you actually want to see the bytes in a text editor after using this, you'd have to convert the bytes into text representing them first, then write that out. Cast ba to an integer and use Integer.toBinaryString to change the byte into text, then write that out. That way you can open the result in a text editor and see the bytes as text (0s and 1s).

Answer (score 1):

The `getBytes()` returns an Array of bytes, so you should iterate throught this array and write it to the file

```
   while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
        ba[]= s.getBytes();
        for (int i=0;i<ba.lenght;i++){
           w.writeInt(ba[i]);
        }            
    }
```

Code not tested

Comment: thanks Moh! Initially I did not understand your comment. I used your iteration method along with Metable's point to "Cast ba to an integer and use Integer.toBinaryString to change the byte into text, then write that out."